# resize content div + image on browser resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What would be the best way to resize a content div to match the browser, keeping a white margin around it, whilst also resizing an image contained within it, so that it keeps a good aspect ratio?

this is the effect i am looking to create: http://www.louisvuitton.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would set the margins of the container whether that is the body or another block element container

```
body {margin:20px;}
```

Comment: body {padding:0;margin:0px;overflow:hidden;}
      #content {margin:25px;}
      img {width:100%;height:auto;}

Comment: except I do not get any margin at the bottom? Also how could I get the image to kind of vertically center itself so that the focus is always on the middle, rather than just showing the top if you resize to very thin.